# Does writing to S3(aws-sdk nodeJS) conflict with listing objects in a bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

please bear in mind that I can, at best, be described as a rookie in both node and amazon S3. I have something app that writes to S3 in the background. I want to read from S3 when the file has been written, and only once it's been written. I attempt to check the number of objects and return the result:

```
function haveFilesBeenWrittenToBucket(bucketName, callback) {
s3.listObjects({ Bucket: bucketName }, function(err, data) {
    const items = data.Contents;
    callback(items);
});
```

}

and the readFile function:

```
OSClient.prototype.readFile = function(params, callback) {
haveFilesBeenWrittenToBucket(params.Bucket, items => {
    console.log("Number of items " + items.length);
        if (items.length > 0) {
            const rl = readline.createInterface({
                input: s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()
            });
            const myArray = [];
            rl.on("line", function (line) {
                const lineArray = line.split(",");
                for (const value of lineArray) {
                    if (isNaN(value)) {
                        // line.split creates string elements, adding extraneous quotation marks in a string and converting
                        // number to string, so there is a need to reverse this process.
                        const slicedElement = value.slice(1, -1);
                        myArray.push(slicedElement);
                    } else {
                        const valueOfNumber = Number(value);
                        myArray.push(valueOfNumber);
                    }
                }
            })
                .on("close", function () {
                    callback(myArray);

                });
        }
         else{
                var myfunction = this.readFile.bind(this, params, callback);
                setTimeout(myfunction, 5000);
            }


    });
```

};

and lastly:

```
     targetClient.readFile(params, function (arrayResult) {
                            logger.info("Read file:" + fileName + OS_FILE_SUFFIX);
                            readArray = arrayResult;
                        });
```

If I put a breakpoint on callback(items) (in 'haveFilesBeenWrittenToBucket') everything works fine and I get back the file written in the bucket, but if not, nothing seems to get written to S3. Seems like some race condition, but I'm really clueless and I really would appreciate some help. Is there a conflict between listing objects and writing to S3 (at least not until much later, in some other test, when it shouldn't be (it's part of a mocha test suite - the readFile is in async.waterfall). I have been on this for days and got nowhere. As I said, it's my first exposure to node, so please be patient with me. Thanks.

Comment: You just saved my life with that link to S3 consistency!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. Firstly, it turns out that my issue was not nodeJS related. Sigh
Secondly, the API now provides a 'waitFor' method for polling whether a bucket or objects exists:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#waitFor-property

Answer (score 1):

S3 provides eventual consistency for list after read. So, you *might* observe the following:

> A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and immediately lists keys within its bucket. Until the change is fully propagated, the object might not appear in the list.

The only situation in which S3 provides immediate consistency is read-after-write for PUTS of new objects (with a minor caveat, documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel)). 
More details at [S3 consistency model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel).

Here is an example of how you can use [async retry](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#retry) to wait for an object and then retrieve its contents (assumed to be text in this example).

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var async = require("async");

var s3 = new aws.S3();
var bucket = 'mybucket';
var iteration = 0;

function waitForObjects(bucket, callback) {
    console.error(`Iteration: ${++iteration}`);

    s3.listObjects({Bucket:bucket}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else if (!data.Contents || !data.Contents.length) {
            callback(new Error("No objects"))
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
}

// Try calling waitForObjects 10 times with exponential backoff
// (intervals of 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, ... milliseconds)
async.retry({
    times: 10,
    interval: function(retryCount) {
        return 50 * Math.pow(2, retryCount);
    }
}, async.apply(waitForObjects, bucket), function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(`Error waitForObjects: ${err}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Object count: ${data.Contents.length}`);

        data.Contents.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(`Object ${index+1} key: ${item.Key}`);

            s3.getObject({Bucket:bucket, Key:item.Key}, function(err, data) {
                console.log(`Object ${index+1} txt: ${data.Body.toString()}`);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I really am a rookie here. I need to list objects in the bucket to check there are at least 1 and then immediately read the file. I don't know when the file will be written, so it could be that it tries to write at the time it lists the objects. Any suggestions? It works with a breakpoint in the place I mention above, but not when I run code straight through

Comment: the real question is how can I work it so that I can get the expected behaviour. A write to S3 at some unspecified time, and then a list of the objects in the bucket that will reliably return the added object. If I list the objects in the bucket and then wait a certain amount of time before listing them again, would that help? If so, how would I do that? Thank you

Comment: If you know that the object will exist, then perhaps you could issue a getObject request after a delay (one second might suffice) but be prepared for that to fail sometimes in which case you should implement some exponential delay and retry (e.g. retry getObject after 1 2, 4, 8 seconds) until you either succeed or have tried too many times in which case you fail the operation. In JavaScript, you can use setTimeout().

Comment: By the way, AWS has a 'serverless' service called Lambda that allows you to execute code when certain events happen, such as when files are stored in S3. Not sure what your app does, so this might not be a good fit, but it might be an option to look into as you would not have to worry about listing S3 objects and waiting for them to appear.

Comment: You just saved my life with that link to S3 consistency! Thank you

Comment: for (const value of lineArray) {
    if (isNaN(value)) {
     // line.split creates string elements, adding extraneous quotation marks in a string and converting
     // number to string, so there is a need to reverse this process.
     const slicedElement = value.slice(1, -1);
     myArray.push(slicedElement);
    } else {
     const valueOfNumber = Number(value);
     myArray.push(valueOfNumber);
    }
   }
   callback(myArray);

Comment: ignore the above comment. Is that for loop in the above code a performance bottleneck? I'm finding that the readFile is not calling callback(myArray) in the time I expect. My code works in debug, but not when run naturally, so there must be a race condition in the above code. Any ideas @jarmod. Thanks so much. It's part of async.waterfall and:var timer = setTimeout(function () { // eslint-disable-line
      return callback();
     },

Comment: I don't know why the close event would not happen. Add a console log into the event handler to verify that it's not being called. If it's still not obvious what's wrong, then create a new stackoverflow question for that specific streaming issue, as it's not really related to the current question (on S3 consistency).