# S3 NodeJS -ListObjects always returns 0

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The code for this question is already here:
[Does writing to S3(aws-sdk nodeJS) conflict with listing objects in a bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553272/does-writing-to-s3aws-sdk-nodejs-conflict-with-listing-objects-in-a-bucket/46554324)

Please be sympathetic, I've been on this problem for days and I'm a complete rookie. I am trying to poll for a list of objects(haveFilesBeenWrittenToBucket method) and then read the file when there are objects (readFile method). If I place a breakpont on the callback(items) in the haveFilesBeenWrittenToBucket, everything works fine. If I don't, I always get 'number of items 0' written out to the console. It is not predictable exactly when the stuff will be written to S3, but it should be within a minute. There appears to be a race condition, and I would be very grateful if anyone could help me out here. I'm desperate for ideas. Thanks so much.

P.S. I was advised to make this a separate question to the one asked in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was barking up the wrong tree- my error had nothing to do with node.